# Math Class, Methods, and random Numbers (Java)

Tags: java, random, methods

I am in **desperate** need for help with a Java Program I need to compete for school! I have been working on this for at least 3 hours for the past 3 days and I can not figure it out.... =( Here are the directions:

Write a program that calls each of the methods of the Math class from the list below and provides output showing the method called, values sent to the method, and the returned results. Each listed method will tell you which values to use. For example:

Listed method:

```
double pow(double a, double b): use 2.0 and 3.0.
```

Your program would display:

```
Math.pow(2.0, 3.0) = 8.0.
```

When calling a method that accepts doubles, use numbers with at least one decimal digit like the example above, even if it's a zero. Remember that numbers with decimals are double literals. Try to use values that will produce easily verifiable results.

Here is the list:

```
double pow(double a, double b): Use 3.0 and 2.0

double sqrt(double x): Use 25.0

int max(int a, int b): Use 6 and 2

double max(double a, double b): Use -50.0 and 7.0

static double random()
```

Sample output:

```
Math.pow(3.0, 2.0) = 9.0

Math.sqrt(25.0)=5.0

Math.max(6,2)=6

Math.max(-50.0,7.0)=7.0

Math.random()= /*-random value-*/
```

Test your program with the values shown in the examples, fix any errors.
Add a method to your program called randomStudy that has no parameters and returns no value. In this method, do the following:

a. Declare three int variables: total, min, and max. Set total to 0, min to 11, andmax to -1.

b. Create a loop that will run 1,000 times. In the body of the loop, generate a random int value between 1 and 10, inclusive. Add this number to your total. If this number is less than min, update min with the new number. If it is greater than max, update max with the new number.

c. After the loop, display the following:

Min value: x
Max value: y
Average: z
Replace x and y with your min and max values. Calculate z by dividing your total by 1000d.
Call your new randomStudy method from the main method.
Highlight and copy the output shown in Eclipse. Paste the output at the bottom of your source code file. Add the text Results:above your output, and then comment out the text your just dded plus the output text. Your commented results should look something like this:

```
/*

Results:

Math.pow(3.0, 2.0)= 9.0

Math.sqrt(25.0) = 5.0

Math.max(6, 2) = 6

Math.max(-50.0, 7.0) = 7.0

Math.random() = -random number-

Min value: 1

Max value: 10

Average: 5.553

*/
```

So, the problem I am having is with the last part about running the loop 1,000 times and then displaying the largest and smallest number out of the 1,000 numbers. And also displaying the mean of the 1,000 numbers. Here is **My code**:

```
 class MathMethodsProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //      Prints the pow method. 

    System.out.println("Math.pow(2.0, 3.0) = " + Math.pow(2.0, 3.0));

   //       Prints the sqrt method

    System.out.println("Math.sqrt(25) = " + Math.sqrt(25));

    //      Prints the max number 

    System.out.println("Math.max( 6, 3) = " + Math.max(6, 3));

   //       Prints the max number

    System.out.println("Math.max(-50.0,7.0) = " + Math.max(-50.0, 7.0));

   //       Prints a random number 
    System.out.println("Math.random(); = " + Math.random());    

    randomStudy();

    }

public static void randomStudy(){
    int total = 0; 
    int min = 11; 
    int max = -1; 
    int newtotal = 0;
    int i; 
    int randomInt = 0;

        for( i = 0; i < 1000; i++){             
             randomInt = 1 + (int)( Math.random() * 11);

             newtotal = (randomInt + total);

            }
        if (randomInt < min) {
            min = 1 + (int) Math.random();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Min: " + min);
        }

        if (randomInt > max) {
            max = 1 + (int) Math.random();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Max: " + max);
         }

         System.out.println("Min value:" + min);
         System.out.println("Max Value:" + max);
         System.out.println("Average:"+ newtotal / 1000d);
    }



}
```

And when I run the code in Eclipse this is the output:

```
 Math.pow(2.0, 3.0) = 8.0
Math.sqrt(25) = 5.0
Math.max( 6, 3) = 6
Math.max(-50.0,7.0) = 7.0
Math.random(); = 0.1824716748725944
Min value:1
Max Value:1
Average:0.008
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that you close the loop iteration before you check the value!

Comment: Furhtermore, you ask `if (randomValue < min)`, but then assing a *new* random value to min: `min = 1 + (int) Math.random();`. Furhterore, if you just call  [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--), it will generate a value between `0` and `1`. Since `floatd`s and `double`s are floored when converted to `int`, you will only get a `1` as result

Comment: If you take care to format your code properly the error could become obvious! You need to check and update your `min` and `max` in each loop's iteration.

Comment: And how do I fix those things? I am a complete beginner to Java. =(

Comment: @BlazeRyder If you take classes in programming, ask your teacher / prof, they get payed to explain things. Or read a tutorial, like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

In your 1000 for loop, you have

```
newtotal = (randomInt + total);
```

Which doesn't increment newtotal, it will just take the last number. It looks like your last number was 8, so the average is 0.008. It would be better to:

```
total = (randomInt + total);
// Then after the for loop is complete, average = total / 1000;
```

Next, for comparing randomInt with min/max, rather than assigning a new random value, you should assign the new min/max based on the last random number (and this needs to be inside your 1000 for loop, not after):

```
if (randomInt > max) {
    max = randomInt;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very close.

You just need to put your if statements inside the for loop and where you wrote

```
max = 1 + (int) Math.random();
```

should read:

```
max = randomInt;
```

(do the same with min so that it reads "min = randomInt;")

Answer (score -1):

Here I am going to provide a code that I created. My purpose is to provide you the idea how to create multiple functions equivalent to the ones that we obtain from the **Math** class. I included comments that help these classes to be self explanatory, I hope this help you. I also include dialog boxes to display data, so it is a good resource if someone is looking for help how to use **javax.swing** class.

The first class ***MyMath.java*** contains the methods used perform all calculations.

```
package com.exercise.lecture2;

/**
 * Create a class call "MyMath" that has the following class methods:
 * static boolean isEven(int x) --> returns true is number is even
 * static long absolute(long x) --> returns the absolute value of x
 * static double hypotenuse (double x, double y) --> returns sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
 * static double max (double a, double b) --> returns max of a or b
 * static double min (double a, double b ) --> returns min of a or b
 * 
 * @author Samuel
 *
 */
public class MyMath {

    /**
     * An even number is an integer which is "evenly divisible" by two. 
     * This means that if the integer is divided by 2, it yields no remainder. 
     * Zero is an even number because zero divided by two equals zero, which despite not being a natural number, is an integer. 
     * Even numbers can be either positive or negative.
     * 
     * @param x
     * @return
     */
    static boolean isEven(int x){
        if (x % 2 == 0) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * In mathematics, the absolute value or modulus of a real number is the number without the sign. 
     * The absolute value of 2 is 2, the absolute value of -2 is also 2.
     * 
     * @param x
     * @return
     */
    static long absolute(long x) {
        if (x >= 0)
            return x;
        else
            return (-1*x); 
    }

    /**
     * The hypotenuse is the side opposite the 90 degrees angle in a right triangle. It is always the longest side.
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return
     */
    static double hypotenuse (double x, double y) {
        return Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));
    }

    /**
     * Maximum of two values
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    static double max (double a, double b) {
        if (a >= b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;       
    }

    /**
     * Minimum of two values
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return
     */
    static double min (double a, double b ) {
        if (a < b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;
    }   

}
```

The second class ***MathClassTest.java*** contains javax.swing class in order to display using dialog boxes.

```
package com.exercise.lecture2;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // importing the javax.swing class in order to use dialog box in my code

/**
 * static boolean isEven(int x) --> returns true is number is even
 * static long absolute(long x) --> returns the absolute value of x
 * static double hypotenuse (double x, double y) --> returns sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
 * static double max (double a, double b) --> returns max of a or b
 * static double min (double a, double b ) --> returns min of a or b
 * 
 * Write an application that allows the user to select between the above methods and
 * returns the response to the user.
 * 
 * @author Samuel
 *
 */
public class MathClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* used to test the functions on MyMath.java class, here is how all of this begin
         * then I change it to make this tester use javax.swing class in order to display using 
         * dialog boxes.
         * 
         // is Even
        System.out.println(MyMath.isEven(-100));

        // Absolute value of an integer
        System.out.println(MyMath.absolute(-10));

        // Hypotenuse of two values
        System.out.println(MyMath.hypotenuse(3, 4));

        // Max of two values
        System.out.println(MyMath.max(3, -4));

        // Min of two values
        System.out.println(MyMath.min(3, -4));

        */

        boolean repeat;
        do {
            //String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name", "Enter name", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choose 'a' or 'A' to determine if a number is EVEN or not. \n" // options
                    + "Choose 'b' or 'B' to determine the ABSOLUTE value of a number. \n" // the (+) sign concatenate the all of the followings Strings as one
                    + "Choose 'c' or 'C' to determine the HYPOTENUSE of two values. \n"
                    + "Choose 'd' or 'D' to determine the MAXIMUM of two values. \n"
                    + "Choose 'e' or 'E' to determine the MINIMUM of two values. \n"
                    + "Choose 'q' or 'Q' to quit this simple application. \n\n" 
                    , "My Math class, by S. Mayol", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); // title bar of the dialog box
            repeat = true;

            if (option.equals("Q") || option.equals("q")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for participating...", "by Samuel Mayol", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                repeat = false;
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                if (option.equals("A")||option.equals("a")){
                    try { // to prevent that the value inserted is an integer and not a letter
                        String val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to deternine if the number is even");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Is the number " + val + " even? " + MyMath.isEven(Integer.valueOf(val)),
                                "Even", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // add a title message on a dialog box
                        repeat = true;
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The input " + option + " is not valid integer, please try again", "WARNING!!!", 
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else if (option.equals("B")||option.equals("b")){
                    try { 
                        String val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number to calculate absolute value of that number");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The absolute value of " + val + " is: " + MyMath.absolute(Long.valueOf(val)), 
                                "Absolute", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        repeat = true;
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The input " + option + " is not valid integer, please try again", "WARNING!!!", 
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else if (option.equals("C")||option.equals("c")){
                    try {
                        String val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first side to calculate the hypotenuse");
                        String val2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second side to calculate the hypotenuse");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The hypotenuse of " + val + " and " + val2 + " is: " + MyMath.hypotenuse(Double.valueOf(val), Double.valueOf(val2)),
                                "Hypotenuse", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        repeat = true;
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The any of the inputs " + option + " are not valid integer, please try again", "WARNING!!!", 
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else if (option.equals("D")||option.equals("d")){
                    try {
                        String val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number to calculate the max value");
                        String val2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number to calculate the max value");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The max of " + val + " and " + val2 + " is: " + MyMath.max(Double.valueOf(val), Double.valueOf(val2)),
                                "Maximum", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        repeat = true;
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The any of the inputs " + option + " are not valid integer, please try again", "WARNING!!!", 
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else if (option.equals("E")||option.equals("e")){
                    try {
                        String val = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first number to calculate the min value");
                        String val2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the second number to calculate the min value");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The min of " + val + " and " + val2 + " is: " + MyMath.min(Double.valueOf(val), Double.valueOf(val2)),
                                "Minimum", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        repeat = true;
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The any of the inputs " + option + " are not valid integer, please try again", "WARNING!!!", 
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The input " + option + " is not valid, please try again", "A, B, C, D, E, or Q", 
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        } while(repeat);
    }

}
```